# IBM Rational DOORS: How to paste as plain text in DOORS Objects?

Tags: requirements, ibm-doors, requirements-management

While writing requirements in IBM DOORS, is it possible to paste some text as plain text (i.e. without original text's formatting) in the 'Heading" or 'Text' attribute of a DOORS Object? 
A simple paste operation keeps the original text formatting that reduces the readability of respective DOORS module. Ofcourse it's possible to copy in notepad first, but I am curious to know if there's a possibility to do it within DOORS.

Answer (score 1):

Not an in-DOORS answer (ha, I slay me!), but what I use is PureText. Install the little program in your Windows system tray, and assign a hotkey combo. Then, instead of Ctrl+V for paste, when I press Win+V the clipboard contents are converted to plain text, and then the clipboard is pasted. (That last sentence is important to note - the clipboard itself is altered. You won't be able to paste the formatted version somewhere else.)

Similar options are probably available on other systems, of course. It's no longer than pressing Ctrl+V, so it satisfies my needs.

http://stevemiller.net/puretext/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this when pasting, but you can use a little DXL to change it afterwards, which is especially useful when the text contains formatting that you cannot remove from within DOORS:

```
Buffer temp = create
temp = obj."Object Text"
string s = tempStringOf temp
obj."Object Text"= s
delete temp
```

This can easily be extended so that your script runs on the entire module, or all selected objects.